# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am attempting to get the sale price from a table and put it into a text box. On my table the sale price is a Decimal variable, and of course the text box is string.. When I run this, there is an exception that is stopping it in my Data Access Layer.

Here is some code:

```
textSellPrice.Text = DAL.Util.getSellPrice(listItemsPricing.SelectedValue.ToString());


public static String getSellPrice(string item)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Price FROM Item it INNER JOIN Customers cu 
        ON it.SalesRep = Cu.SalesRep WHERE CustomerID='" 
        + HttpContext.Current.Session["SelectedCustomer"] +
        "' AND ProductID='" + item + "'";
    string dt = AdoUtil.GetDataColumn(sql);
    return dt;
}



    public static string GetDataColumn(string sqlQuery)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, GetACESConn());

            if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                cmd.Connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result = reader.GetString(0);
                }


            if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                cmd.Connection.Close();

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return result;
        }
    }
```

So is there something completely obvious that I am missing?
Thanks for any helpful insight to this, and if any other code could be of use, I can provide it. Thank you

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're selecting a price, which is presumably a decimal. So don't call `reader.GetString(0)` - call `reader.GetDecimal(0)` and store the result in a `decimal` variable. If you *really* want to convert everything into a string, just call `GetValue(0).ToString()`.

While you're there, *please* fix this:

```
string sql = "SELECT Price FROM Item it INNER JOIN Customers cu ON it.SalesRep = Cu.SalesRep WHERE CustomerID='" + HttpContext.Current.Session["SelectedCustomer"] +
    "' AND ProductID='" + item + "'";
```

This is just begging for a [SQL Injection Attack](http://bobby-tables.com). *Don't* put values directly into SQL like this. Instead, use *parameterized* SQL and specify the values for those parameters. See [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.

Next up, *don't* catch `Exception`, and don't return a value when an exception is thrown as if nothing had happened... you'll be masking errors for no reason.

Comment: and yes I am aware of the sql injection attack threats. When I run into a little hitch like I had yesterday towards the end of my day I resort to anything to try and solve it, and once solved I again use the parameters. Thank you for your help and concern

Answer (score 3):

`CustomerId` is declared as a numeric type in the database, but you are trying to read it as a string. If you must have your result as a string, you can either:

- read it as a numeric type (say, a `decimal`) and convert to string in C#, or
- change your SQL to cast it to `varchar` on the RDBMS side

On a side note, you should not bake parameter values into your queries to avoid [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/); you need to use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06) instead.